# .NET Web API (not Core) - Creating a Patch operation in an Entity Framework controller

Tags: c#, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, patch

I'm using `Entity Framework` in a `.NET Web API` (not Core) project with an Angular front end. **Currently, the only examples of patch implementation I can find is for ASP.Net Core products - so I'd firstly like confirm if `patch` is even possible in plain ol'  `ASP.Net Web API` (not Core)**.

I'd like to implement `patch` in some of my controllers, but by default, the Entity controller does not seem to come with code for a patch operation. Instead it comes with `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE`. What code is needed in my Entity controller so that patch requests are valid? Is there a way to specify this when adding a new Entity controller, or must it always be entered in manually?

My controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using api.Models;
using api.Models.my_model;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;

namespace api.Controllers.my_model
{
    public class myController : ApiController
    {
        private myCodeFirst db = new myCodeFirst();

        // GET: api/my
        public IQueryable<myTable> GetmyTable()
        {
            return db.myTable;
        }

        // GET: api/my/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(myTable))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetmyTable(int id)
        {
            myTable myTable = db.myTable.Find(id);
            if (myTable == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(myTable);
        }

        // PUT: api/my/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutmyTable(int id, myTable myTable)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != myTable.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(myTable).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!myTableExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/my
        [ResponseType(typeof(myTable))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostmyTable(myTable myTable)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.myTable.Add(myTable);


            db.SaveChanges();


            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = myTable.ID }, myTable);
        }

        // DELETE: api/my/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(myTable))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeletemyTable(int id)
        {
            myTable myTable = db.myTable.Find(id);
            if (myTable == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.myTable.Remove(myTable);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(myTable);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool myTableExists(int id)
        {
            return db.myTable.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: Use the `[HttpPatch]` attribute.  In fact you should likely use all the Http method attributes instead of relying on the naming conventions

Comment: Agreeing with maccettura. Naming conventions like this can actually result in poor naming of methods, and thus poor maintainability and readability.

Comment: Thanks guys. Can either of you post an example of a controller implementing a patch? All the examples I found online are for `ASP.NET Core` and use namespaces like JsonPatchDocument, which doesn't seem to be available in `.Net Web API` (non Core), which is what I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

The PATCH method is a request method supported by the HTTP protocol for making partial changes to an existing resource.
There is some JSON Patch operations you can see:

**Add**

```
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/a/b",
    "value": "foo"
}
```

**Remove**

```
{
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/a/b"
}
```

**Replace**

```
{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/a/b",
    "value": "foo"
}
```

**Copy**

```
{
    "op": "copy",
    "from": "/a/b",
    "path": "/a/c"
}
```

**Move**

```
{
    "op": "move",
    "from": "/a/b",
    "path": "/a/c"
}
```

**Test**

```
{
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/a/b",
    "value": "foo"
}
```

---

In ASP.NET Core you specify patch methods with [HttpPatch] attribute.
For getting data in this methods you should use `JsonPatchDocument<TModel>` exist in `Microsoft.ApsNetCore.JsonPatch` namespace where `TModel` is your entity that you want convert to it. Another package that will be useful is AutoMapper. You can install it from NuGet package manager as below:

```
Install-Package AutoMapper
```

and referenced it in your controller.

Now it's time to look at an example in ASP.NET Core Web API:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PartiallyUpdateBook([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<BookModel> patchDoc)
{
    // If the received data is null
    if (patchDoc == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // Retrieve book from database
    var book = await _context.Books.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)

    // Check if is the book exist or not
    if (book == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Map retrieved book to BookModel with other properties (More or less with eexactly same name)
    var bookToPatch = Mapper.Map<BookModel>(book);

    // Apply book to ModelState
    patchDoc.ApplyTo(bookToPatch, ModelState);

    // Use this method to validate your data
    TryValidateModel(bookToPatch);

    // If model is not valid, return the problem
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Assign entity changes to original entity retrieved from database
    Mapper.Map(bookToPatch, book);

    // Say to entity framework that you have changes in book entity and it's modified
    _context.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;

    // Save changes to database
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // If everything was ok, return no content status code to users
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sajad. We are using `ASP.net Web API`, not `ASP.NET Core Web API` - will this still work in that case?
Also, is it possible to implement a patch without a third party addon? Or is having a good addon pretty important?

Comment: All of ASP.NET Web APIs support this attributes as I know. Absolutely you can implement the sample code without Automapper package. But you should write many codes! This package is powerful and I recommend use it in all of your projects. Automapper homepage: https://automapper.org and source code on GitHub: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Hmm...for example, even in `.net Core`, JsonPatchDocument requires an install for JsonPatchDocument:  `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch`. In `.NET Web API`, this install is not compatible and will not work. So in .net web API (not core), I don't think I have the ability to use JSON Patch Document. There really is not a lot of documentation about this online - I really hope Patch is possible for .NET Web API but I'm unsure.

Comment: Ok, it's just for .net core. So you can use this package ```Install-Package Marvin.JsonPatch``` for .net framework.

Comment: Thanks Sajad, I actually found this extension just before you posted - there was a choice between it, or another JsonPatch extension by MyQuay, or using ODATA. I think this Marvin.Jsonpatch may be a better choice than having all of ODATA's dependencies just for a patch. Any way you could check my question here and see if you can comprehend his documentation for *implementing `JsonPatchDocument` class on the client*?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527311/kevindockxs-jsonpatch-in-an-angular-net-web-api-project  Thanks for your advice so far

Comment: On further research I think the documentation for KevinDockx's `Marvin.JsonPatch` was not written for sending requests from a separate front end framework like Angular. I'm really struggling with the concept of how to send my patch data from `Angular` to `Web API` aside from manually building a dynamic JsonPatchDocument of my own within Angular. And manually building it out seems like a challenge or there wouldn't be so many extensions to build the request for you. I've hit a brick wall with this one.

Comment: Hi @KyleVassella, did you make a breakthrough? I am going through the same