# JsonPatch in an Angular/.NET Web API project

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, crud, patch, json-patch

I'm utilizing KevinDockx's `JsonPatch` extension for Visual Studio. My project uses `.NET Web API` (not Core) and `Angular (6)`. `.Net Web API` doesn't support the `JsonPatchDocument` namespace, thus the need for KevinDock's `JsonPatch` extension.

I'm reading through his documentation here: https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch/blob/master/README.md

`JsonPatch` consists of two parts:

**On the client (consumer of the API)**: the JsonPatchDocument / JsonPatchDocument class to build what's essentially a change set to be applied to your object on your API side.

**At (Web) API level**: an ApplyTo method to apply those changes to your objects.

But I'm having trouble understanding part 1, where he builds a JsonPatchDocument class on the client. In my case, I assume that means I need to build this `JsonPatchDocument` somewhere in the Angular. The code for this step is:

```
JsonPatchDocument<DTO.Expense> patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<DTO.Expense>();
patchDoc.Replace(e => e.Description, expense.Description);

// serialize
var serializedItemToUpdate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc);

// create the patch request
var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, "api/expenses/" + id)
{
    Content = new StringContent(serializedItemToUpdate,
    System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, "application/json")
};

// send it, using an HttpClient instance
client.SendAsync(request);
```

However, I'm unsure of how to implement this portion of code in my Angular code, or if I'm even interpreting that part of the instructions correctly. For example, say I've already installed `JsonPatch` on my API via the NuGet package manager console - how then could I reference JsonPatchDocument from Angular (`JsonPatchDocument<DTO.Expense> patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<DTO.Expense>();`), since Angular does not have this install? Has anyone worked with `JsonPatch` in an Angular project enough to interpret this part of the documentation for me?

Comment: Hey Mate, you ever found a solution for this or just used the [FormBody] approach?

Comment: Hi @Dash, unfortunately, JsonPatch proved too complex with not enough documentation for our needs. We ended up going with standard PUT and POST requests and abandoning PATCH requests altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm currently implementing similar to your need and ended doing something mentioned in the following link.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/webapi-webapi-patch-update-using-frombody-parameter-in-web/